# Cannot import source package in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an issue with using source package in PyCharm.
Project structure looks like this

```
- project 
  - source
    - endpoint / user / _get / module1.py
    - layer / common / module2.py
  - tests
    ...
```

module2.py:

```
def somefunction():
  return 'sometext'
```

module1.py

```
import common

print(common.module2.somefunction())
```

In PyCharm preferences, under project structure i added source and source/layer as sources. In editor everything is correct, common package is visible, but when I run

```
python module1.py
```

It is showing

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

Comment: Recommended practice is adding an  `__init__.py` in every directory and using absolute qualified names in the imports. Otherwise chances are you'll be having problems with cyclic imports latter. See [PEP 395](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `__init__.py` files inside `layer` and `common`.

Comment: It does not help

Comment: Try also creating the `__init__.py` in the directories on the path to `module1`.

Comment: nothing changed. I think it may be related to console settings

Comment: From what location do you run the `python module1.py` command? Is the project/source in your environment path?